# Column name disappears after resampling dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, keyerror

I have a dataframe in which i need to calculate the means of ozone values for every 8 hours. The problem is that the column after which i am doing the resampling('readable time') disappears and cannot be referenced after the resampling.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("o3_new.csv")

del data['latitude']
del data['longitude']
del data['altitude']

sensor_name = "o3"

data['readable time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['readable time'], dayfirst=True)

data = data.resample('480min', on='readable time').mean()  # 8h mean
data[str(sensor_name) + "_aqi"] = ""

for i in range(len(data)):
    data[str(sensor_name) + "_aqi"][i] = calculate_aqi(sensor_name, data[sensor_name][i])

print(data['readable time']) #throws KeyError
```

Where `o3_new.csv` is like this:

```
,time,latitude,longitude,altitude,o3,readable time,day
0,1591037392,45.645893,25.599471,576.38,39.4,1/6/2020 21:49,1/6/2020
1,1591037452,45.645893,25.599471,576.64,48.4,1/6/2020 21:50,1/6/2020
2,1591037512,45.645893,25.599471,576.56,53.4,1/6/2020 21:51,1/6/2020
3,1591037572,45.645893,25.599471,576.64,36.4,1/6/2020 21:52,1/6/2020
4,1591037632,45.645893,25.599471,576.73,50.4,1/6/2020 21:53,1/6/2020
5,1591037692,45.645893,25.599471,577.09,37.4,1/6/2020 21:54,1/6/2020
```

What to do to keep referencing the 'readable time' column after resampling?

Answer (score 1):

What would you like the column to contain? `mean` makes no particularly good sense for time columns. Also, the resampler makes your `on` column the index, so just `data.reset_index(inplace=True)` may make you happy.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use `data.index` to access the values still, directly after the resample